# Debug delay-loaded dll in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi

I can't find the delay-load dll in Modules Window in visual studio, How I can set some configurations to debug this kind of dll?
I am debugging a c++ project and this delay-loaded dll is 3rd party. The PDB file is also copied into the dirctory with the coresponding dll.

**Intention**:I want the source cpp files correponding to the delay-loaded dll can be debugged.

**Note**: The referenced dll are marked as `<DelayLoadDLLs>` in .vcxproj file.

Comment: You don't need to do anything special. If you can't find the delay-load dll in Modules Window it does not mean that you can not debug it.

Comment: Visual Studio's debugger isn't well prepared for setting breakpoints on to-be-loaded modules. WinDbg (or [WinDbg Preview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/debugging-using-windbg-preview)) is a better tool here. With it you can [`sxe ld <module_of_interest>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/sx--sxd--sxe--sxi--sxn--sxr--sx---set-exceptions-) and have the process break into the debugger as the module loads. From there you can `bp` or `bu` breakpoints on whichever location.

Comment: Actually I can't debug this dll and I want it does(First question on stackoverflow, so there are some unclear content). So it should be a not-supported function in Visual studio and I must depend on other development tools?

Comment: You need to step into the source before setting breakpoints or drag the source into Visual Studio.